# Changing the base color of ploty_express parallel_categories diagram

Tags: python, colors, plotly, plotly-express

Creating a parallel_categories with ploty express

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.tips()
fig = px.parallel_categories(df)

fig.show()
```

[image]

gives a diagram with blue base color.

I would like to **change the base color** without using graph object. Just the overall color from blue to e.g. gray.

Assigning a color via a column is in my example not possible. Using `color_continuous_scale` also aims at a different color change.

Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

**express**

I have found that this can be achieved with plotly.express. Create a color list and specify a continuous color scale gray.

```
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np

color = np.zeros(len(df), dtype='uint8')

df = px.data.tips()
fig = px.parallel_categories(df, color=color, color_continuous_scale='gray')

fig.update_layout(coloraxis_showscale=False)
fig.show()
```

[image]

**Note:**
Once again, there is a discrepancy in the output graph. The data specified for color is also added to the graph, which defeats the purpose of the express.

**graph_objects**

The same graph can be created by specifying each category using the graph object. So we are creating a list of numbers to give to the colors, either 0 or 1. Then we set the color scale to gray for both 0 and 1. This approach was inspired by the [official reference](https://plotly.com/python/parallel-categories-diagram/#parallel-categories-linked-brushing).

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np

df = px.data.tips()

color = np.zeros(len(df), dtype='uint8')
colorscale = [[0, 'gray'],[1, 'gray']]

fig = go.Figure(go.Parcats(
    dimensions=[
        {'label': 'sex',
         'values':df['sex'].tolist()},
        {'label': 'smoker',
         'values':df['smoker'].tolist()},
        {'label': 'day',
         'values':df['day'].tolist()},
        {'label': 'time',
         'values':df['time'].tolist()},
        {'label': 'size',
         'values':df['size'].tolist()}],
    line={'colorscale':colorscale, 'cmin':0,'cmax':1,'color':color,'shape':'hspline'}
))

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so I guess it is graph Object or photoshop ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Original answer here is helpful but missed that there is a parameter in `px.parallel_categories()` for `dimensions`, and you can use that to only show what you want - that is, to not show the final column called color.

The below code is the same as the other answer except has the `dimensions=[...]` included (and also the df was defined out of order).

```
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np

df = px.data.tips()
color = np.zeros(len(df), dtype="uint8")


fig = px.parallel_categories(
    df,
    dimensions=["sex", "smoker", "day", "time", "size"],
    color=color,
    color_continuous_scale="gray",
)

fig.update_layout(coloraxis_showscale=False)
fig.show()
```

[image]